# Help me to know how to generate random number under certain distribution.

Tags: probability, functions

I want to generate random number base on a certain distribution.

Its pdf(probability density function is $f(x)=\alpha/x$ where $x∈[x_{max},x_{min}]$, $\alpha=1/\ln(x_{max}-x_{min})$

I made a vba function by using rnd function.

```
invf = Exp(rnd / Application.WorksheetFunction.Ln(Mat2(i, j) - Mat1(i, j))
  'where invf=generating number
  '      Mat2(i,j)=x_max:
  '      Mat1(i,j)=x_min
```

is it right? or plz help me to know

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean 
$$ \alpha = \frac {1} {\ln x_{\max} - \ln x_{\min}}$$ 
It is because
$$ \int_{x_{\min}}^{x_{\max}} \frac {1} {x}dx = \ln x_{\max} - \ln x_{\min}$$
and you need the pdf integrate to $1$. Then similarly, we can calculate the CDF:
$$ F_X(x) = \frac {\ln x - \ln x_{\min}} {\ln x_{\max} - \ln x_{\min}}
= \left(\ln \frac {x_{\max}} {x_{\min}}\right)^{-1}\ln \frac {x} {x_{\min}} , x \in (x_{\min}, x_{\max} )$$
And thus we can find the inverse transform by setting $U = F_X(X)$:
$$ U = \left(\ln \frac {x_{\max}} {x_{\min}}\right)^{-1}\ln \frac {X} {x_{\min}} \iff 
X = x_{\min}\exp\left\{\ln \frac {x_{\max}} {x_{\min}}U \right\}
= x_{\min} \left(\frac {x_{\max}} {x_{\min}}\right)^U$$

And this will be your required transform which require no spreadsheet function.